# Models implemented as Scopes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this situation now where I’ve implement models as a plain JavaScript object. So you can synchronously ask the model for a value and you can subscribe to event to get notified about updates to the model. But I’m not happy doing it this way. It leads to a lot of code and checks everywhere.

Now, I’ve been thinking, wouldn’t it be better to make use of Angular and use isolated scopes for the models? This way anyone interested in a particular value can just watch the model for changes.

Example:

```js
function UserService($rootScope) {
  var model = $rootScope.$new(true);
  this.getModel = function() {
    return model;
  };
}

function userWidget(userService) {
  var user = userService.getModel();
  user.$watch('isLoggedIn', function(isLoggedIn) {
    //React to if the user i signed in or not...
  });
}
```

Is it a good idea or a bad idea? Any thoughts about this? How have you solved this?

---

Even if silly, here is a small demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JTggQ0FVYpo4saLmjLAo

---

Thanks!
/Martin

Comment: Interesting...  I'm not sure what the ramifications are of placing an isolated scope as a property on another scope...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it, but I would personally have a benefit to describe before I just randomly did that. $rootScope.$new is actually sort of heavy - an AngularJS scope has a lot of additional reference objects like siblings and parents. If you have 5, who cares? But if you have 5,000 that's going to be heavy for the garbage collector to manage. It's totally justified if it gives you some advantage, but if it's just for the sake of itself I wouldn't bother.

Is there a reason you rely on variable hoisting so much in your example? It's usually viewed as a by-product or anti-pattern, so it may throw off other developers who help maintain your code. Or are you flying solo? :)

Comment: Are you referring to the `$inject`s? Due to the duplication in defining your injectables, having the them close to the function arguments makes it a lot easier to deal with and spot any errors. No, we are a team of 5 JS devs.